# rmarkdown encrypted output loses plotly and leaflet plots

Tags: r, r-markdown, password-protection

I want to generate an Rmarkdown document with a password.

One possible solution is to encrypt the html output with `encryptedRmd`. I tried this:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "John Doe"
date: "18/11/2020"
output: 
  encryptedRmd::encrypted_html_document:
    css: theme.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
library(plotly)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}


fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
fig

```

## Map

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}


m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m  # Print the map

```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

The problem is that this solution appears to be designed to simpler reports than the one i need to protect eith password. As a result, the encrypted version of the html don't render properly plotly and leaflet results.

What can I do?